# How to insert ® value in database

Tags: mysql, database, drupal-7

I am inserting users from drupal6 to drupal7 using a custom script. I am using db_insert function. In one of the D6 entry I am getting ® mark in a field and because of this that particular value become blank in D7 database. D6: imatter® -> D7:

Anyone has any idea about how to insert this value in database?

Collation is same in both database: utf8_general_ci And in phpmyadmin its look like same as above, means no html code for ®

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&reg;` for ® in the html.

Let me know if this helps.